# Random variables problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $X, Y, Z$ be non-independent random variables. How is the Sylvester criterion applied using the matrix of covariance?

I have calculated $E[X^2]$ using the formula, but how can I use the Sylvester criterion on the calculated matrix?

Answer (score 2):

I will write $E$ for expectation (instead of $M$ for mean) and will assume that by dispersion $D(X)$, you mean the standard deviation, so that the variance $E[X^2] - E[X]^2 = E[X^2]$ is $1$. The basic idea is that the covariance matrix

$\begin{bmatrix} 
E[X^2] & E[XY] & E[XZ] \\
E[XY] & E[Y^2] & E[YZ] \\
E[XZ] & E[YZ] & E[Z^2] \\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & E[XY] & \frac{1}{2} \\
E[XY] & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

is positive semi-definite (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114072/what-is-the-proof-that-covariance-matrices-are-always-semi-definite)). By [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), this means that all three upper left square submatrices have non-negative determinant. In particular, letting $x = E[XY]$, this gives $1 - x^2 \geq 0$ and $x^2 - \frac{1}{2}x - \frac{1}{2} \leq 0$, which yield $-\frac{1}{2} \leq E[XY] \leq 1$. Conversely, any positive semi-definite covariance matrix can be realized by random variables (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163470/generating-correlated-random-numbers-why-does-cholesky-decomposition-work)), so these bounds are sharp.

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy - Schwarz inequality $|M(XY)| \leq \sqrt {MX^{2}}\sqrt {MY^{2}}=1$. Hence $-1 \leq M(XY) \leq 1$. For an example where $M(XY)=1$ take $X$ with standard normal distribution and $Y=X$; you can always find a $Z$ such that $EXZ=\frac 1  2$ and in this case we also have $EYZ=\frac 1  2$. Hence the largest value of $M(XY)$ is $1$.

Similarly the lowest value of $M(XY)$ is $-1$.

Comment: Aren't you assuming that the variances of $X$ and $Y$ are both $1$? What is your definition of dispersion ?  @OscarTheMighty